# jquery - pass a function as argument to another function, check for return value each time calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function that each time returns different value:

```
this.imageArr = [ "1.png", "2.png" ]

this.changeImg = function () {
    return $( "#Img" ).attr("src", "images/" + this.imageArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.imageArr.length)]);
}
```

This function each time it is called changes randomly src of image.

now, i have second function that manages multiple animation

```
$.fn.animationNSteps = function ( className, delay, steps, infinite, visibility, func ) {
      [...]
      $(this).animationNSteps( className, delay, steps, infinite, visibility, func )
}
```

Last parameter is "func". If it is given (it sometimes is given, sometimes is not) it should randomly change picture using previous function `changeImg()`. Unfortunately if I call it like this:

```
$("#title").animationNSteps ( class, 3000, 3, true, true, obj.changeImg )
```

It randomly takes picture for the first call, but next one and all the others are still the same. How to call `changeImg()` function each time to change the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#title").animationNSteps ( 
    class, 3000, 3, true, true, 
    function(){
        return obj.changeImg();
    } )
```

Comment: what does the animationNSteps function do?

Comment: it controls multiple steps of css animation, depending on parameters making it infinite, multiple, delays... it enhances pure css controlm starts animation from begining and so on.. thats why sometimes it has a special function (like changeImg()) because in time of animation it changes an image

Comment: I tested this on a simple example and it works. Probably somewhere inside `.animationNSteps()` method the return value of the `changeImg()` method is stored and reused later and the method is never called again. So you should take a look at how `.animationNSteps()` method uses the function you provide as a paramter.

Comment: `.animationNSteps` doesnt mess with `func` parameter... If i read it via `if ( func ) { console.log(func)}` in a first line of `.animationNSteps` it returns to console: _function () { display.changeFace() }_ . Can I call it somehow? Like $(func), func() or sth?

Comment: You were right.. I had error in .animationNSteps function.. next call passed func as fifth parameter instead of sixth.. now it works.. +1 for you.. thanks!